# I am unable to dismiss a GameCenter leaderboard/view

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

GameCenter is able to open. However, when the "done" button is pressed on the top right corner to dismiss GameCenter, GameCenter still remains open. How do I close GameCenter?

Below is my code:

```
- (void) presentLeaderboards
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [vc presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Close");
    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You never set a delegate for your `GKGameCenterViewController` so your `gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:` method is never called. You should have found this yourself through a little debugging.
2. Call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on `viewController`.

Your code should be more like:

```
- (void) presentLeaderboards
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        leaderboardController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [vc presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Close");
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Adding the line:

```
leaderboardController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
```

may lead to a new error. If so, you need to add the following to the .m before the `@implementation` line.

```
@interface MyViewControllerNameHere () <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>

@end
```

If you already have the class extension, just add the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` part.